# centering \dot over multiple letters using Asana Math

Tags: horizontal-alignment, unicode-math

When using Asana Math, my derivation dots wander around.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmathfont{Asana Math}

\begin{document}
\[
\dot{\mathit{vx}} + \dot{x}
\]
\end{document}
```

If I uncomment `\setmathfont`, the dots are centered above the last letter. If I uncomment `\usepackage{unicode-math}` as well, the dots center as intended.

What do I need to do in order to obtain a nice, centered dot with both unicode math and Asana?

edit: As suggested, I also tested this behavior with Gyre Pagella as main font. This does not seem to change the output.

```
% dnf info texlive-unicode-math | grep Version
Version     : svn38337.0.8b
% dnf info texlive-luatex | grep Version 
Version     : svn37242.0
```

edit2:
Aside from the system installation, I also tried the most recent texlive distribution. (lualatex 0.95.0, unicode-math 0.8c) It has the same problem.

edit3: I should have made this clear from the beginning: I am using lualatex (and constrained to it due to some tikz libraries I use).

Comment: This is what I get [click here for the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9v9dJ.png) I just added `\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}` for getting a matching italic font. Can you add some information about the TeX distribution you are running and the version of `unicode-math`?

Comment: I just installed the most recent texlive stable. Same problem. What version of unicode-math and lualatex are you using?

Comment: I have the most recent versions; Debian usually lags behind. The real version number of the package can be seen in the log file.

Comment: Which debian are you on? Stable?

Comment: Not at all. I use TeX Live provided by MacTeX and on Linux boxes I install the standard TeX Live, not the Debian one.

Comment: Now I see you're using LuaLaTeX. Well, with it I can see the shift, too. It's not a font problem, because it happens with every math font.

Answer (score 1):

With an up-to-date TL 2016:

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}% loads fontspec itself
\setmathfont{Asana Math}

\begin{document}
    \[
    \dot{\symit{vx}} + \dot{x}
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
unicode-math.sty    2015/09/24 v0.8c Unicode maths in XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
ifluatex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
   expl3.sty    2016/10/19 v6730 L3 programming layer (loader) 
expl3-code.tex    2016/10/19 v6730 L3 programming layer 
l3xdvipdfmx.def    
ucharcat.sty    2015/11/19 v0.03 ucharcat for luaLaTeX (DPC)
  xparse.sty    2016/10/19 v6730 L3 Experimental document command parser
l3keys2e.sty    2016/10/19 v6730 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
fontspec.sty    2016/02/01 v2.5a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
fontspec-xetex.sty    2016/02/01 v2.5a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
 fontenc.sty
  eu1enc.def    2010/05/27 v0.1h Experimental Unicode font encodings
  eu1lmr.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
xunicode.sty    2011/09/09 v0.981 provides access to latin accents and many oth
er characters in Unicode lower plane
 eu1lmss.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
graphicx.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2016/07/10 v1.0t Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
   xetex.def    2016/07/11 v4.10 LaTeX color/graphics driver for XeTeX (L3/RRM/
JK)
fontspec.cfg
  fix-cm.sty    2015/01/14 v1.1t fixes to LaTeX
  ts1enc.def    2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
filehook.sty    2011/10/12 v0.5d Hooks for input files
unicode-math-xetex.sty    
   t3cmr.fd    2001/12/31 TIPA font definitions
```

Comment: strange I get the dot very much shifted to the left with a tl2016 updated yesterday. The log contains :``* OpenType feature 'Style=MathScript' (+ssty) not available for font``
``* 'Asana Math' with script 'Math' and language 'Default'.``

Comment: @jfbu: I used the default `Asana.math` from TL

Comment: I have `Asana-Math.otf` (TL on Linux)

Comment: ah thanks. XeTeX used a `ttc` font for me. (TL on Mac)

Comment: This explains it. There is also an `otf` font indeed, and if I force use of it the dot is ok. My set-up is with symlinks in `$HOME/Library/Fonts` where XeTeX looks for fonts, to TeXLive repertories. If I remove the symlink to truetype repertory it find the otf variant.

Answer (score 1):

The issue appears with LuaLaTeX, but not with XeLaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmathfont{Asana Math}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
\dot{\mathit{vx}} + \dot{x} \\
\dot{\symit{vx}} + \dot{x} \\
\dot{\mathit{eff}}+\dot{x} \\
\dot{\symit{eff}}+\dot{x}
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

**Output with LuaLaTeX**

[image]

**Output with XeLaTeX**

[image]

Of course it is in general unacceptable using `\symit` in place of `\mathit`, as shown by the bottom lines.

**Workarounds.**

Use `\symit` if it doesn't disrupt your typesetting.

If you can't, `\dot{\text{$\mathit{vx}$}}` should do:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmathfont{Asana Math}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
\dot{\text{$\mathit{vx}$}} + \dot{x} \\
\dot{\symit{vx}} + \dot{x} \\
\dot{\text{$\mathit{eff}$}}+\dot{x} \\
\dot{\symit{eff}}+\dot{x}
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have no problem with `xelatex` _and_  with `lualatex`